# VBA IE download on lock screen

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, ui-automation

Hi I am using VBA macro to dl files from one intranet website...its working great but not when windows is locked (win + L). To download the file I am using UIAutomationCore.dll, so No send keys. I am using IE11.

example of use of UIAutomationCore.dll [IE11 Frame Notification Bar Save button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31489801/ie11-frame-notification-bar-save-button?rq=1)

If you would have tip how to save files also on locked pc I would be very greatfull.
Thanks

Comment: So I'm presuming that you tried the solution in your referenced post but it's not working for you?

Comment: the solution in ref. post is working only when windows is not locked